# get input type="number" tag to run on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have two html5 input number controls on my page and I would like to use their value through code behind. but when I add the runat="server" attribute I still cannot catch them in the cs file. is there a way to do it?

**here are my controls:**

```
<input id="hour_input" type="number" min="1" max="12" step="1" value ="1" runat="server"/>
            <input id="minutes_input" type="number" min="0" max="60" step="5" value ="0" runat="server"/>
```

it gives: "the name 'hour_input' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft released an update for the .NET framework 4 that allows the TextBox to support HTML 5 attributes.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871

See **Fonction 3**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" type="some-HTML5-type" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In you page load you can simply add this:

```
 hour_input.Attributes.Add("type", "number");
```